# Has anyone studied the derived category of Higgs sheaves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, derived-categories, higgs-bundles

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $\Omega^1_X$ be the sheaf of holomorphic $1$-forms on $X$. A *Higgs bundle* on $X$ is a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ together with a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\phi: E\to E\otimes \Omega^1_X$ (the Higgs field) such that $$\phi\wedge \phi=0:  E\to E\otimes \Omega^2_X.$$

If we replace the holomorphic vector bundle $E$ by a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{E}$, then we get a *Higgs sheaf* on $X$. See for example [On Gieseker stability for Higgs sheaves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03100).

Since the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves has been intensively studied in algebraic geometry, I wonder whether the bounded derived category of Higgs sheaves (or related concept) has ever been defined or studied in literatures.

Comment: This is possibly related to the full subcategory of $D^b(Coh(T^*X))$ consisting of objects whose support is finite/proper over $X$

Comment: In a special case where $ X $ is a curve, $ \operatorname{Hom}(E, E \otimes \omega_X) \cong \operatorname{Ext}^1(E,E)^{\vee} $ by Serre duality. Therefore Higgs sheaves on $ X $ correspond to the cotangent bundle of the moduli stack of vector bundles on $ X $.